# Pandas, summing values in a row to form a "totals" column

Tags: python, pandas

So I've been trying to get the sum of my rows and have them add into a new column. My data is something along the lines of:

```
     Animal  num1  num2 
0    22-14  36.6   213      
1    39-14  42.44  141      
2    40-14  39     157
```

I've tried things such as:

```
df['sum'] = df['num1'] + df['num2']
```

But that just combines the information together, it doesn't sum it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like your columns aren't filled with numbers, but are instead full of strings. Can you do `print(df['num1'].dtype)` for me?

Comment: It yields "object" once I type that in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that your columns are actually strings, not numbers. When you try to sum the columns, the strings just get concatenate (e.g. `'cat' + 'dog'` becoming `'catdog'`).

You can convert them to numbers using [`pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html).

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """     Animal  num1  num2 
0    22-14  36.6   213      
1    39-14  42.44  141      
2    40-14  39     157"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+', dtype=str)

# You can ignore the code above this point, I was just re-creating your DataFrame.
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

After this, it should work exactly as you said above, so:

```
df['sum'] = df['num1'] + df['num2']

print(df)
#  Animal   num1  num2     sum
#0  22-14  36.60   213  249.60
#1  39-14  42.44   141  183.44
#2  40-14  39.00   157  196.00
```

Answer (score 3):

The sum command takes an axis argument that can be used to sum either columns (1) or rows(0).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,5,2],'b':[5,2,9]})
df['c'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

This method only accept numbers, you first column is a string so you will have to parse that. For example if you want to remove the hyphen from the numbers you could use the command:

```
df['Animal'] = df['Animal'].apply(lambda x: int(x.replace('-','')))
```

Or if you want to ignore that first column entirely you can simply not include it .

```
df['sum'] = df.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis = 1)
```